# which of the following functions can't be a solution of given ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Which of the following functions can't be  the  solution of ODE $$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$$ for some continuous functions $p(x), q(x)$ are functions on some interval.

> $1)$ $e^{3x}$
>
> $2)$ $x^{2}$
>
> $3)$ $x\left | x \right |$
>
> $4)$ $x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$

If I suppose $q(x)=-9$ and $p(x)=0$ ,then I will get option 1 right, but to solve for other options, are there any general proof of this situation? Please, help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "some interval" in your question is not a simplification of "in some interval containing $0$" (or equivalent words), we can avoid the singular behaviour in the proposed $y$s.

For all cases, let "some interval" be $(1,2)$.  Then singular behaviour in $y$ must be on the interval $(1,2)$ to be relevant.  Equivalently, for any $y$ that satisfies the differential equation, any extension of $y$ outside of the interval of definition of $p$ and $q$ is equally valid, including extensions that are not twice differentiable at every point of the exterior of the interval.

Then each of the given $y$s is a solution for the following particular choices of $p$ and $q$.

1) $p(x) = 0$, $q(x) = -9$.

2) $p(x) = 0$, $q(x) = -2x^{-2}$.

3) $p(x) = 0$, $q(x) = -2x^{-2}$.  Notice that the given $y$s for cases 2 and 3 are identical on $[0,\infty)$, so are indistinguishable on our chosen "some interval".

4) $p(x) = 0$, $q(x) = x^{-4}$.

---

On the other hand, if $0$ must be included in the interval of definition of $p$ and $q$, then $x|x|$ and $x \sin(1/x)$ are not differentiable at $x=0$, so cannot be the solution of a second order, homogeneous, ordinary differential equation with continuous coefficients, which coefficients are defined on an interval containing $0$.

[Update:]  Further, as observed by [@Lutzl](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/115115/lutzl), inserting the second proposed solution, $y = x^2$, into the differential equation and specializing to $x = 0$, yields
$$  2 + p(0) \cdot 0 + q(0) \cdot 0 = 0  \text{,}  $$
a contradiction, regardless of choice of $p$ and $q$.  Therefore, the second option is also not a solution of the equation if $0$ is in the interval of definition of $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Because $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ leads to the zero solution for all $p,q$, option 2) is also not possible if $0$ is included in the interval.